# How create shared style for path control in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, .net-standard

I have next XAML code:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Path Style="{StaticResource UserIcon}"/>
        <Path Style="{StaticResource UserIcon}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And style in Styles.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="UserIcon"
       TargetType="Path">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Data" Value="M0 58l0 13 70 0 0 -12c-39,-33 -70,-1 -70,-1zm53 -40c0,-10 -8,-18 -18,-18 -9,0 -17,8 -17,18 0,9 8,17 17,17 10,0 18,-8 18,-17z" />
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Problem: style used only one time. Second path control don't had Data from style, and in designer (and execution too) it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ93S.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem here is the fact that `Data` is not a dependency property (**Update: This is not true in fact, so it rather seems as a bug)**. The only way I found to reuse path is to reuse the geometry data only as a simple string:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <x:String x:Key="UserIconGeometry">M0 58l0 13 70 0 0 -12c-39,-33 -70,-1 -70,-1zm53 -40c0,-10 -8,-18 -18,-18 -9,0 -17,8 -17,18 0,9 8,17 17,17 10,0 18,-8 18,-17z</x:String>
</Page.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <Path Data="{StaticResource UserIconGeometry}" Fill="Red" />
    <Path Data="{StaticResource UserIconGeometry}" Fill="Red" />
</StackPanel>
```

[image: Properly rendering]